# Implement email confirmation with digit code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I want to implement email confirmation with digit code for my .net core web app.
I make use of the GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync from the UserManager class, but it returns a token instead of a digit code. I think I should create a custom implementation using the IUserTokenProvider interface, but I cant find any example.

How can I implement this using the IUserTokenProvider?

Comment: providing the code sample from your solution would be a good idea, otherwise it`s a wide

Comment: https://andrewlock.net/implementing-custom-token-providers-for-passwordless-authentication-in-asp-net-core-identity/

Comment: Do you want this digit code to be TOTP (Time-based One-time Password), i.e. do you want it to expire?

Comment: Yes, I do.  I want it to expire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an existing implementation in ASP.NET Core Identity that does that.

The [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) class (implementation of [IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider.cs) interface) generates 6-digit tokens that expire.

`TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider` is further inherited by [EmailTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/EmailTokenProvider.cs), but [GenerateAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/ec82890133bee41e1ee00f01d581c0fe1d84f0d0/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs#L33-L42) method is reused from `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider` (not overridden).

These classes use user's security stamp to generate tokens, and provide their own modifiers, but the actual token generation is done by [GenerateCode](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/ec82890133bee41e1ee00f01d581c0fe1d84f0d0/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs#L70-L83) method from [Rfc6238AuthenticationService](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/Rfc6238AuthenticationService.cs) class.

So, you can use the existing implementations:

- `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider`
- `EmailTokenProvider` (it does the same as the above one)
- `Rfc6238AuthenticationService` if you really want to customize the token

Comment: How can you make it return 4 digits? I've been trying to figure it out. I inherited from PhoneNumberTokenProvider<> and have overridden the GenerateAsync, but if you get the code from the base.GenerateAsync call you can't manipulate it because it is already stored. Where is the code stored? In memory? Should I just roll my own storage in the GenerateAsync and ValidateAsync methods?

Comment: As per usual, I post then come up with an answer on my own. I posted a gist of how I solved the problem of 4 digit token/codes. This could also be used to change the time window for validity to work with other services/use cases. https://gist.github.com/jmichas/dab35d9b8e916eae8936322465d76b66

Answer (score 1):

You use that token to generate a action callback url

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(
               "ConfirmEmail", "Account", 
               new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, 
               protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, 
               "Confirm your account", 
               "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" 
                                               + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");
            // ViewBag.Link = callbackUrl;   // Used only for initial demo.
            return View("DisplayEmail");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: Yes, I know. But i want send digit code (fro example "123468") instead link

Comment: Dont do that. Using MS solution is tested, secure, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To build on Marko's answer;

We also have to tell Identity what token providers we want to use for the different kinds of tokens to make the `UserManager`-convenience methods like `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync()` or `ConfirmEmailAsync()` use a specific provider.

We do this by configuring the identity `TokenOptions`:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Token settings.
    options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "MyCustomEmailTokenProvider";
    ...
});
```

Or together when registering the new provider using the fluent API:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
    {
        options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "MyCustomEmailTokenProvider"
    })
    .AddTokenProvider<MyCustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider>("MyCustomEmailTokenProvider");
```

The implementations Marko mentions and a few more providers gets added by default by `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` that can be used without registering any additional providers by using their names:

- `TokenOptions.DefaultProvider`, uses `DataProtectorTokenProvider` (the default provider used when no explicit configuration exist
- `TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider` uses `EmailTokenProvider`
- `TokenOptions.DefaultPhoneProvider` uses `PhoneNumberTokenProvider`
- `TokenOptions.DefaultAuthenticatorProvider` uses `AuthenticatorTokenProvider`