# Email confirmation using a custom verification token/code in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement a short code (6digits) for Email Confirmation using Asp.Net Identity Core.

Currently, I am using the existing implementation which is [TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider.cs) .

Everything works fine, it generates the 6 digit code that I want using this line of code
`var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "EmailTokenProvider", "EmailConfirmation");` ,

it also verifies if the code entered is valid or not using this method here `var isValid = await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, "EmailTokenProvider", "EmailConfirmation", token);`.

My problem is, when I am trying to call the method `await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);` it says **InvalidToken**, do I need to implement my own ConfirmEmailAsync? As I also dig deep into it, it calls the `SetEmailConfirmedAsync`, do I also need to override the current implementation for that by creating my own custom IUserEmailStore?

Thanks!

Here are some of the sample references:
[Implement email confirmation with digit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512305/implement-email-confirmation-with-digit-code),
[Custom Verification Code/Token in Asp .Net Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963854/custom-verification-code-token-in-asp-net-identity)

Comment: Could you share a little more code? Unfortunately the github link you posted 404's out for me.

Things that come to mind:

1. It seems as though you are generating good tokens, do you save them down to a data store yourself or is there a package you are using that does this for you?

2. If this package didn't create tables for you to store the tokens, it is very likely you will have to write your own ConfirmEmailAsync function.

Comment: The link you provided is 404,  So I can only make a simple judgment based on your question, In my opinion, this question may caused by `encode and decode of verification tokens`, So you can try to refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25111928/invalid-token-while-verifying-email-verification-code-using-usermanager-confirm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

Instead of

```
var token = await _userManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync(user, "EmailTokenProvider", "EmailConfirmation");
```

Click [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generateemailconfirmationtokenasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We have to tell Identity what token providers we want to use for the different kinds of tokens to make the `UserManager`-convenience methods like `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync()` or `ConfirmEmailAsync()` use a specific provider.

We do this by configuring the identity `TokenOptions`:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Token settings.
    options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "MyCustomEmailTokenProvider";
    ...
});
```

Or together when registering the new provider using the fluent API:

```cs
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
    {
        options.Tokens.EmailConfirmationTokenProvider = "MyCustomEmailTokenProvider"
    })
    .AddTokenProvider<MyCustomEmailConfirmationTokenProvider>("MyCustomEmailTokenProvider");
```

There also exist few token providers that gets added by default by `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` that can be used without registering any additional providers by using their names:

- `TokenOptions.DefaultProvider`, uses `DataProtectorTokenProvider` (the default provider used when no explicit configuration exist
- `TokenOptions.DefaultEmailProvider` uses `EmailTokenProvider`
- `TokenOptions.DefaultPhoneProvider` uses `PhoneNumberTokenProvider`
- `TokenOptions.DefaultAuthenticatorProvider` uses `AuthenticatorTokenProvider`